# C++ String Comparison using == operator

Tags: c++, string

I have a question about comparing strings in C++. My code below is supposed to check if a word is a palindrome (spelled the same way forward and backwards). The problem is that my if statement (s1 == s2) never evaluates to true. I have the feeling that in memory these two strings are different, but I don't have any concrete proof. Any advice? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1, s2;
    cin >> s1;

    for(int i = 0; i <= s1.size(); i++){
        s2.push_back(s1[(s1.size() - i)]);
    }
    cout << s1 <<endl;
    cout << s2 <<endl;


    if(s1 == s2){
        cout << "Correct" <<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Incorrect" <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My best advice is to display the values of the two strings and check for yourself. Failing that, run your program under a debugger. Step through each line and decide if it is behaving as intended.

Answer (score 4):

This is going out of bounds for the strings

```
for(int i = 0; i <= s1.size(); i++){
    s2.push_back(s1[(s1.size() - i)]);
}
```

A string only has chars in the range `0..size()-1`. You are both counting and indexing one position too far.

Answer (score 3):

But you should better use the following instead of your loop:

```
s2.assign(s1.rbegin(), s2.rend());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in the string comparison. Have a look at how you're building the reversed string.

Answer (score 0):

Index is out of range in your case. Here is the correct code (i is initialized with 1, not 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= s1.size(); i++){
        s2.push_back(s1[(s1.size() - i)]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `s1.size() - i - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `i` starts at 0, you will access `s1[s1.size()-0]`, which will return the null character.  Note that the solutions suggesting you use `s1.size() - i - 1` are **wrong**, as you are iterating up to and including `s1.size()`, which means you would at some point access `s1[-1]`.  That's much worse than accessing `s1[s1.size()]`, as the behaviour is undefined.  Start iterating at 1, and then you can leave the rest of the code unchanged (but please do indent it!).

As others have mentioned, defining `s2` as `std::string s2(s1.rbegin(), s1.rend());` is even clearer.

Answer (score -4):

ofcourse. you're comparing the pointers of the two vars.
you should use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) function

fix: you need to use:
[string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)

good luck

Comment: sorry, you should use instead 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: No, the string `operator==` *is* using string::compare, so they are equivalent.